# jQuery fade a div inside a canvas

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to fade a DIV inside a `<canvas>` tag. (is that even allowed? I assume so since it's an element).  You know the standard [jQuery fadeIn](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) and here is what I use for style:

```
    <style type="text/css">
<!--
    #canvas {
       background:red;
       z-index:0;
       position:relative;       
    }
    .txt {
        z-index:2;
        background:blue;
        display:none;
        position:absolute;
        top:0;
        right:0;
        width:200px;
    }
-->
</style>
```

and simply enough here is my HTML (ignore the body.. I have it all.. this is to cut it short):

```
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas"><div class="txt">Welcome to the Game</div></canvas>
</body>
```

I tried a simple fadein and it's not working..

Comment: do you have the jquery code for it?

Comment: Why does it need to be inside the canvas element

Comment: Here is the jQuery `$('.txt').fadeIn('fast', function() {});`... and it has to be inside... if not.. it won't work?

Comment: Seems to work just fine..http://jsfiddle.net/UpAT7/

Comment: do you have a `$(document).ready`? if so can you post all the code in that?

Comment: Content inside the canvas element is fallback content.  The div will only show up if the browser does not support canvas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [WHATWG spec](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html):

> The contents of the canvas element, if any, are the element's fallback content.

"Fallback content" is displayed only when the browser does not support a type of element:

```
<canvas>
    <div>Looks like you need to upgrade to a canvas-aware browser!</div>
</canvas>
```

You should put the div *after* the canvas element and use CSS to position it visually over the canvas.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [WHATWG spec for the canvas element](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#the-canvas-element)

> When authors use thecanvas element, they must also provide content that, when presented to the user, conveys essentially the same function or purpose as the bitmap canvas. This content may be placed as content of thecanvas element. The contents of thecanvas element, if any, are the element's fallback content.

It certainly appears that your content isn't fallback content. If it isn't, perhaps you should use conventional canvas methods to display your text.